# Xcode IOS transition views with a tab view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am developing an IOS app using Swift and have a tab view controller. I start the app at the SecondViewController to allow the user to insert their information, upon clicking save I would like to programmatically transition to a different view. When I use the following code, the view transitions however the tab bar disappears.

```
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)        
    let home = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home") as FirstViewController
    self.presentViewController(home, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Should I not be presenting the view and just using a different form like segue or something?

Again this is a tab bar controller.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `presentViewController` method, your particular view controller get's displayed modally above your current tab bar and navigation stack.

To keep your tab bar visible you either have to push your new view controller on the current navigation stack by calling the method `pushViewController(..)` on your current navigation controller, **or** - this is actually the right thing in your particular situatuin, assuming that you defined you `FirstViewController` in your storyboard and connected it to the first tab in your `UITabBarController`— you can simply tell your tabBarController to select the particular segmentedIndex (in this case 0).
Something like this should help:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```